# ActionResult parameter coming in as null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have seen a couple related questions to this, but I cannot seem to solve my exact instance.  I have a url such as `http://127.0.0.1/UTS/Unit/J0000001`.  That is, my controller is `UTS`, my action is `Unit` and there is an optional parameter `c_number`.

I have my **route** configured as follows:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Unit",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{c_number}",
    defaults: new { controller = "UTS", action = "Unit", c_number = "" }
  );
```

Then, my **action** in my controller as:

```
    public ActionResult Unit(string c_number)
    {
        UnitViewModel uvm = new UnitViewModel();
        uvm.unit = pacificRepo.Units.FirstOrDefault(g => g.c_number == c_number);
        uvm.geoLocation = pacificRepo.GeoLocations.FirstOrDefault(g => g.geo_location.Latitude == uvm.unit.geo_location.Latitude && g.geo_location.Longitude == uvm.unit.geo_location.Longitude);
        return View(uvm);
    }
```

Whenever I go to the example URL I gave above, `c_number` comes up as `null`.  It should be `J0000001`.  Does anyone see something blatantly obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Is that the only route you have defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you define it in your `Route` you don't need to add parameter for your `c_number`.You can get your value from `RouteData` dictionary.That `c_number` parameter  has value only if you pass it as `QueryString` like `http://someurl.com/UTS/Unit?c_number="J0000001"`

```
public ActionResult Unit()
{
    var cNumber = RouteData.Values["c_number"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works.  I am able to extract it as long as it is passed like a QueryString.  Is it possible to define the route like I have above?  So that you could access it via `http://127.0.0.1/UTS/Unit/J0000001`.  This seems to work if the parameter is named "id" -- is this a special case variable?

Comment: @gnychis `RouteData.Values["c_number"]` should work with your current RouteConfig.Your definition is correct.just delete the parameter and get the value from RouteData

Comment: ohhh I see what you mean now.  Thanks for this!